# Maximum number of edges in bipartite $C_4$-free graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

> Show that a $C_4$-free bipartite graph between two vertex parts of
> sizes of $a$ and $b$ has at most $ab^{1/2}+b$ edges.

Let's introduce some basic notations: $\binom{X}{2}$ means the family of 2-subsets of $X$ and $v\sim A$ means that $v$ is adjacent to any vertex in $A$.

*Proof:* Suppose that $G=G[X,Y]$ is a bipartite graph with vertex parts $X$ and $Y$ such that $|X|=a,\ |Y|=b$ and with $m$ edges.

1. Assume that $a\geq b$ and consider $S=\{(A,v)\in \binom{X}{2}\times Y: v\sim A\}.$ One can obtain the following upper bound for the size of $S$: $$|S|=\sum \limits_{A\in \binom{X}{2}} \sum_{\substack{v\in Y\\v\sim A}} 1 =\sum \limits_{A\in \binom{X}{2}} |\{v\in Y: v\sim A\}|\leq \sum \limits_{A\in \binom{X}{2}}1=\binom{a}{2}.$$ In the same way one can obtain lower bound for the size of $S$:
   $$|S|=\sum \limits_{v\in Y} \sum_{\substack{A\in \binom{X}2{} \\v\sim A}} 1=\sum \limits_{v\in Y} |\{A\in \binom{X}{2}: v\sim A\}|\geq \sum \limits_{v\in Y}|\{A\subset N(v): |A|=2 \}|=\sum \limits_{v\in Y}\binom{\deg (v)}{2}.$$
   Combining bounds, we obtain: $$\sum \limits_{v\in Y} \binom{\deg(v)}{2}\leq \binom{a}{2} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \sum \limits_{v\in Y}\deg(v)^2-\sum\limits_{v\in Y}\deg(v)\leq a^2-a.$$ Since $\sum \limits_{v\in Y}\deg(v)=m$ and $\sum \limits_{v\in Y}\deg(v)^2\geq \frac{m^2}{b}$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we obtain: $$\frac{m^2}{b}-m\leq a^2-a \Leftrightarrow m^2-bm+(ab-a^2b)\leq 0 \Rightarrow$$ $$m\leq \frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ab+4ba^2}}{2}\leq \frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4ba^2}}{2}\leq \frac{b}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}a\sqrt{b}.$$
2. If $b\geq a$, then performing analogous reasoning one can show that $m\leq \frac{a}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}b\sqrt{a}.$

Combining both cases we obtain that $e(G)\leq \min \left(\frac{b}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}a\sqrt{b}, \frac{a}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}b\sqrt{a} \right).$

And you see that what I've obtained is very close to the answer of the problem but I do not see what should I change in order in my reasoning.

If someone can show it, then it would be great!

Comment: Wouldn't that be less than the minimum, not the maximum? If $e(G) \leq m$ and $e(G) \leq n$, then $e(G) \leq \min\{m, n\}$. (I mean, the maximum isn't *wrong*; it's just not as tight.)

Comment: @BrianTung, of course! Edited! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, OP has correctly solved the problem.
I basically repeated what the OP has done.

---

We can use similar reasoning used to show a bound of the number of edges for general $C_4$-free graphs using double counting "cherries" ($K_{1, 2}$).

**Proof.** We count cherries with the middle point on the right ($b$ nodes). We have the number of cherries =
\begin{align}
\sum_{v \in Y} \binom{d_v}{2} \geq b \binom{\frac{1}{b} \sum_{v \in Y} d_v}{2} = b \binom{m/b}{2} = m(m-b)/2b,
\end{align}
where we use Jenson's for the first inequality.

On the other hand, we have the number $\leq \binom{a}{2}$. Otherwise, by Pigeonhole we will have a $K_{2,2} = C_4$.

Therefore, we have $m(m-b)/2b \leq a(a-1)/2$, which is
$$m^2 - bm -ab(a-1) \leq 0.$$
The axis of symmetry is $m = b/2$.
Since $ab^{1/2} +b > b/2$, when $m > ab^{1/2} + b$,
$$m^2 - bm -ab(a-1) > (ab^{1/2} + b)^2 - b * (ab^{1/2} + b) - ab(a-1) > 0,$$
completing the proof.

Comment: Why do you think that I did not used $C_4$-freeness? I've used it here $|\{v\in Y: v\sim A\}|\leq 1$.

Comment: I see. Sorry  for that!

Comment: I think actually I just repeated what you have done

Comment: I did not read your answer in detail but what is the main difference between our approaches? I also counted the number of "cherries", i.e. $K_{1,2}$ copies in $G$.

Comment: I think the only difference is the last step. We do need to exactly solve the quadratic equation but we can just show that when $m$ exceeds the bound the inequality does not hold.

Comment: your last step of the proof is a bit confusing. What are you doing there?

Comment: I am showing that when $m > ab^{1/2} +b$, then $m^2 - bm - ab(a-1) > 0$ and thus the ineq does not hold

Comment: now that makes sense. It was really easy and I was so close to solve but ..) I’ll accept your answer! Thank you! +1

Comment: Sorry that I did not read your trial carefully... I could have made it much clearer and more concise.